# How to round a whole number in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to round an integer in javascript to its previous decimal.

```
Ex.:
15 to 10.
16 to 10.
21 to 20.
29 to 20.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can even use `Math.floor()`

```js
var num = 24;
var round = Math.floor(num / 10) * 10;
console.log(round)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```js
parseInt(15/10) * 10
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own function to do that

```
function intFloor(num){
  let temp = num%10;
  return num-temp;
}
console.log(intFloor(15));
```

if you know prototype You can add this to prototype

```
Number.prototype.intFloor = function(){
  let temp = this%10;
  return this - temp;
}
console.log((52).intFloor()) // result 50
```